# ugarchforecast() external.forecasts=list() format

Tags: r

I'm using ruGarch() with garch(1,1), and arma(2,0) mean model with external regressors:

```
spec=ugarchspec(
variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(1,1)),
mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(2,0),
external.regressors=cbind(diff6,t10,special)))

fit=ugarchfit(spec=spec,data=hlb, solver='hybrid')
```

all good so far. When I want to do forecasting for n.ahead=1, given a set of three new variables for my regressors (13,2,0.43) I use :

```
fcat=ugarchforecast(spec,data=hlb,n.ahead=1,
```

externalforecasts=list(13,2,0.43))

and I get the following error:

```
ugarchforecast-->error: parameters names do not match specification
Expected Parameters are: mu ar1 ar2 mxreg1 mxreg2 mxreg3 omega alpha1    beta1
Error: Exiting
```

Does anyone know if I can pass in new values for my external regressors and get the forcas value using this function? I know there's a way to svae the "Spec" fitted coef, add a row of data and do it that way, but just curious if this simpler way would work.

thanks-

Comment: No data, missing objects. No way to answer the question in a principled fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use fit instead of spec?

```
fcat = ugarchforecast(fit, n.ahead=1, externalforecasts = list(13,2,0.43))
```